# How run .exe file in Inno Setup with parameters

Tags: parameters, executable, exe, inno-setup

Please, I try run a .exe file that in cmd console runs in the following manner:

nameFile.exe -inf fileDriver.inf install

In the Inno Setup i have the follow:

```
var
command: Srtring;

Begin

command := 'nameFile.exe -inf fileDriver.inf install';
command := AddQuotes(command);
Exec(command, '', 'C:\pathOfFileName', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
S:= SysErrorMessage(ResultCode);
MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

The message show that the parameters is invalid, how can run the exe file with the parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your [`Exec`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_exec.htm) call, you need to pass the command parameters to the second parameter of the function call. Try to use something like this instead:

```
...
Exec('nameFile.exe', '-inf fileDriver.inf install', 'C:\pathOfFileName', 
      SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
...
```

The [`Exec`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_exec.htm) function is declared as:

```
function Exec(const Filename, Params, WorkingDir: String; 
  const ShowCmd: Integer; const Wait: TExecWait; 
  var ResultCode: Integer): Boolean;
```

Comment: Drat! Beat me by about 10 keystrokes and a mouse click! :-) +1

Comment: I had to do *something* with at least part of what I'd written. ;-) You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you, but i put '-inf fileDriver.inf install' and work... =)

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! I've used `Exec` quite a long time ago and wrote this from top of my head.