# Inno setup Exec() other 3rd party executable with command parameters

Tags: exec, inno-setup, nsis, silent-installer

I have below script to execute a 3rd executable made by NSIS with command /s (silent install) in inno setup for my application.

```
[Files]
Source: "..\programB.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; AfterInstall: InstallProgramB


[Code]
procedure InstallProgramB;

var
ResultCode: Integer;

begin
  // Install programB and wait for it to terminate
  if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\programB.exe'), '/s', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
     ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
   begin
    MsgBox('Failed to install programB!' + #13#10 +
      SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that it pop-up the wizard of programB.exe which is not "silent install".  I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542615/how-run-exe-file-in-inno-setup-with-parameters)
and place the command line parameter "/s" to second argument(as you can see), but /s seems doesn't work.
Any comments are welcome

Comment: That should IMHO work. If it doesn't, there might be some requirement for other parameters to be specified (not sure about it). You can ultimately hide the GUI process by specifying `SW_HIDE` flag for the `ShowCmd` parameter (instead of `SW_SHOWNORMAL`), but that merely hides the real problem of executing this setup. Does this command line work if you execute if from command prompt ?

Comment: @TLama  good point!!  the correct command should be /S, not /s....

Comment: [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#silent)

Comment: Oh, so their parameters are case sensitive (they even mention it *Passing /S on the command line (case sensitive)*). Amateurism :) Feel free to post and accept your own answer with the solution.

Comment: Yes. It is. what a mistake I have made.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it as well (from program that has so few parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Check [NSIS Help](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#silent)

```
Passing /S on the command line (case sensitive))
```

So, the correct parameter should be /S, not /s. It's case sensitive